# Including isolated Qt objects in .cpp file

Tags: c++, qt, include

I want to use a library that utilizes the QT-class QVector2D to calaculate B-splines (library: https://github.com/ejmahler/SplineLibrary). But I can't figure out how to get the includes / linking right using a simple .cpp file and compiling with g++.

This is my attempt

```
// test.cpp

// My attempt at including the QVector2D class
#include </home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qconfig.h>
#include </home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include </home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h>
#include </home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qvector2d.h>

// For spline library
#include <SplineLibrary/spline_library/spline.h>
#include <SplineLibrary/spline_library/vector.h>
#include <SplineLibrary/spline_library/splines/uniform_cr_spline.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<QVector2D> splinePoints{
    QVector2D( 0, 1), 
    ...
    };

    UniformCRSpline<QVector2D> mySpline(splinePoints);
    QVector2D interpolatedPosition = mySpline.getPosition(0.5f);
}
```

Compiling with g++ 5

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test
```

gives

```
/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:63:28: fatal error:
QtCore/qconfig.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

I have verified that the file qconfig.h exists and that it is in the path as included.

I'm guessing my error is either in how I try to include the QT-headers, that I need to link it somehow.

How do I properly include a single Qt component (in this case QVector2D) and compile the project using g++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never specify absolute paths in you includes. If someone else wants to use your code, they would need to modify all the files to point to the correct headers on their system. Apart from that you're using internal headers that you're not supposed to include yourself. At the very top of the [Qt documentation for `QVector2D`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector2d.html) you can find what header you're supposed to include to use the `QVector2D` class.

So test.cpp should look like this:

```
#include <QVector2D>

// For spline library
#include <SplineLibrary/spline_library/spline.h>
#include <SplineLibrary/spline_library/vector.h>
#include <SplineLibrary/spline_library/splines/uniform_cr_spline.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<QVector2D> splinePoints{
        QVector2D( 0, 1), 
        ...
    };

    UniformCRSpline<QVector2D> mySpline(splinePoints);
    QVector2D interpolatedPosition = mySpline.getPosition(0.5f);
}
```

### Compiler flags

Now, since you have a custom installation path for Qt5.8, the compiler can't find the header in the default search path, so when compiling this file you need to tell the compiler where to search for the Qt headers. As indicated by the line `QT += Gui` in the documentation I linked above, `QVector2D` is part of the QtGui sublibrary, so you need to include the headers in the directory `/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui/`. The compiler flag to do so is `-isystem /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui`.

However, the QtGui headers themselves depend on QtCore headers, but their path is given relative to the `/home/user/Qt5.8/gcc_64/include` directory, so in order for the compiler to find the header files the QtGui headers depend on you also need to add the compiler flag `-isystem /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include`. Btw this is also the reason why you got the error `QtCore/qconfig.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`, there is no such file `QtCore/qconfig.h` in the directory where `test.cpp` is located, nor is there one in the system include path, and you didn't give the compiler the additional path where to look for it.

So the compilation should be successful when executing `g++ -std=c++14 -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -fPIC -c test.cpp` (assuming that the compiler previously didn't have any problem to find `SplineLibrary`s includes).

### Linker flags

The previous command just compiles `test.cpp` (note the `-c` flag), but doesn't produce a binary that you can run. The linker has the same problem as the compiler - it doesn't know where to find the precompiled Qt libraries to link against unless you tell it where to look for them. The flag to do so is `-L/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib`.

In addition to telling the linker where to look for the precompiled libraries, you also need to tell it which ones you're using. As I've mentioned before, `QVector2D` is part of the QtGui sublibrary, so you need to add `-lQt5Gui`. Since QtGui depends on QtCore, `-lQt5Core` also needs to be added.

Assuming you used the default installer, your installation of Qt only includes dynamic libraries, so you also need to tell the linker to store the information where to find the library files in the created binary. The flag you need to add for this is `-Wl,-rpath=/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib`.

So putting everything together, the final command you need to run is `g++ -std=c++14 -fPIC -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -isystem /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -L /home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib test.cpp -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui`.

If you use clang instead of gcc, the same command runs just fine if you replace `g++` by `clang++`.

Comment: Wow, I mean, I know I'm not supposed to say "thank you" and stuff according to the commenting / posting guide lines, but you really put a lot of effort into writing an extensive and instructive reply to me, a total stranger. It is very much obliged!
Your answer did indeed solve the Qt error, but g++ spewed some 15 new errors at me with regard to header files in SplineLibrary. I think I'll just leave this library and try to make do with Eigen instead, which have some limited support for splines.

Comment: @storluffarn I don't know the spline library, but if it isn't header-only and you didn't install it somewhere where the compiler/linker is already looking for it then it might just be the same problem and you also need to add include- and linker paths for it.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno, examples of errors are: `error: extra qualification ‘SplineLibraryCalculus::’ on member ‘gaussLegendreQuadratureIntegral’ [-fpermissive]"` and `error: ‘maxT' was not declared in this scope`. 
I just get the feeling that you're just not supposed to use this library in this way. Might be worlds colliding, it is developed by a guy at some movie studio in LA, presumably for doing animations, and I want to use it for calculating energy levels in quantum mechanics.